# UIView repeating animation stops when UIView disappears

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have a iOS application with a tab bar at the bottom, like this:
[image: tab bar]

The white circle at the center of the tab bar pulsates by fading in and out repeatedly. Here's the code that does the pulsate animation:

```swift
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 1.4, delay: 0, options: [.repeat, .autoreverse], animations: {
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 0.7, animations: {
        self.recordingPulsatingCircleView?.alpha = 1
    })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0.7, relativeDuration: 1.4, animations: {
        self.recordingPulsatingCircleView?.alpha = 0
    })
}, completion: nil)
```

The problem is that when the tab bar disappears, by, for example, being hidden behind another view, or when I click the home button and bring back the app again, the animation stops, and the white circle disappears, like this: 
[image]

I expect it to continue animating because I set `.repeat` as one of the `options`. Any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved my problem by replacing the `UIView.animateKeyframes` with `CABasicAnimation`, then setting the property `isRemovedOnCompletion` of `CABasicAnimation` to `false`. This way the animation no longer stops when the view is placed out of the screen. Here's the code:

```swift
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.toValue = 1
animation.duration = 0.7
animation.autoreverses = true
animation.repeatCount = .infinity
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false   //Set this property to false.
recordingPulsatingCircleView?.layer.add(animation, forKey: "pulsating")
```

Comment: Isn't "OnCompletion" and "view disappearing" 2 different things? Glad that it solves the problem, but I don't understand how it actually works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I used CABasicAnimations.

[Link to doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cabasicanimation)

To combine several animations, you must use CAAnimationGroup.

[Example link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938223/how-can-i-create-an-cabasicanimation-for-multiple-properties)

Comment: I tried replacing UIView animations with CABasicAnimation. But the animation still stops the view disappears.

Comment: Your answer did lead to me finding the correct solution. See my answer posted next to yours.